# Why can't I assign lambda to Object?

Tags: java, java-8

I was trying to assign a lambda to Object type:

```
Object f = ()->{};
```

And it gives me error saying:

```
 The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
```

Why is this happening, and how to do this?

Comment: What method would be defined by this lambda?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not possible. As per the error message `Object` is not a functional interface, that is an interface with a single public method so you need to use a reference type that is, e.g.

```
Runnable r = () -> {};
```

Comment: True, but of course you can assign any object to an Object variable if you really think you want it. `Object f = (Runnable) () -> {}`.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski u should have answered... but why casting is necessary here?

Comment: @texasbruce without the cast the target type is just `Object`

Answer (score 15):

This happens because there is no "lambda type" in the Java language.

When the compiler sees a lambda expression, it will try to convert it to an instance of the functional interface type you are trying to target.  It's just syntax sugar.

The compiler can only convert lambda expressions to types that have a single abstract method declared. This is what it calls as "functional interface". And `Object` clearly does not fit this.

If you do this:

```
Runnable f = (/*args*/) -> {/*body*/};
```

Then Java will be able to convert the lambda expression to an instance of an anonymous class that extends `Runnable`. Essentially, it is the same thing as writing:

```
Runnable f = new Runnable() {
    public void run(/*args*/) {
        /*body*/
    }
};
```

I've added the comments `/*args*/` and `/*body*/` just to make it more clear, but they aren't needed.

Java can infer that the lamba expression must be of `Runnable` type because of the type signature of `f`. But, there is no "lambda type" in Java world.

If you are trying to create a generic function that does nothing in Java, you can't. Java is 100% statically typed and object oriented.

There are some differences between anonymous inner classes and lambdas expressions, but you can look to them as they were just syntax sugar for instantiating objects of a type with a single abstract method.

Comment: Not quite _just syntax sugar_. In Java, a lambda is more efficient than creating an anonymous class.

Comment: Boris, in terms of *raw metal* execution and bytecode performance, there may be a difference between the two. But in terms of coding, there is not. I added this to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Thiago Negri: There *are* differences “in terms of coding”. First, the meaning of `this` and `super` is entirely different. Second, you are not allowed to use lambda parameter names which would hide local variables while method parameters may. Third, using `_` (a single underscore) as lambda parameter name will generate an error while you get away with a warning in an inner class. And, of course, anonymous inner classes may extend non-`interface` classes and have fields and more than one method, etc. Just to name some differences.

Comment: @Holger: I didn't know. Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Holger: "First, the meaning of this and super is entirely different." Yes, but nobody said that the stuff inside cannot be simplified as part of the syntactic sugar. Where `this` or `super` is used in a lambda, it is the same as `OuterClass.this` or `OuterClass.super` in an inner class. "Second, you are not allowed... Third, using _ ..." A lambda is a syntactic sugar for an anonymous class, meaning a lambda can be written as an anonymous class; not that an anonymous class can necessarily be written as a lambda.

Comment: @newacct: you can formulate an inner class being semantically equivalent, that’s not the question. You can even formulate equivalent code without an inner class, however, the point is that the transformation is not as easy as it has been written in this answer. Given the amount of differences on source level and that it works entirely different on the low level, the big question is why it is considered to be syntactic sugar of *inner* classes. Actually, you may consider both, inner classes and lambda expressions as syntactic sugar for top level classes with certain characteristics.