# Java 8: Type inference fails when mapping objects to method references

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, method-reference

I have an array of objects of classes that extend this abstract class in a variable `handlers`:

```java
public abstract class RequestHandler {

    public boolean handleGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handlePost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handlePut(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleDelete(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleTrace(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleOptions(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleConnect(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handlePatch(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I now want to map this collection to a list of BiFunction's:

```java
    final List<BiFunction<HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Boolean>> getHandlers = Arrays.stream(handlers)
            .<BiFunction<HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Boolean>>map(handler -> handler::handleGet)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if I remove the explicit generic type specification:

```java
    final List<BiFunction<HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Boolean>> getHandlers = Arrays.stream(handlers)
            .map(handler -> handler::handleGet)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get a compilation error at `handler::handleGet`:

> Object is not a functional interface

Why doesn't the compiler correctly infer the type here?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828246/why-cant-i-assign-lambda-to-object esp. the second answer?

Comment: @GhostCat So it seems like an edge-case where Java simply can't infer the return type of the lambda and therefore sets it to Object, OK. Thank you.

Comment: That works, too ... thank you very much