# Can I use lambda functions to return something?

Tags: java, lambda

I wanted to use lambda function to return a value and I am not able to so the same. Why doesn't this work?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(() -> {
            String s = "Akhilesh";
            return s;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're passing a function where you **meant** to pass a `String`

Comment: A lambda is the implementation of a functional interface. A functional interface is an interface that contains precisely one abstract method. The parameter[s] for method `println()` are not functional interfaces.

Comment: Although not a perfect duplicate, this is pretty much equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/q/26828246/2185599. I understand that a way of learning a thing is to print the thing out, but in this case it's simply the case that you *can't* call `println` with a lambda expression. Try one of the more conventional examples of assigning it to a `Supplier<String>` type then running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer has given the explanation of *why* it would not work. Here is how you *can* make it work. In simpler terms, you must give Java some suggestion as to what the lambda should turn into, or else it wouldn't compile. (I suggest accepting their answer since it gives the actual reason for your problem. I am only posting this because I can empathize with wanting to print everything when learning anything Java and the frustration this must have come with.)

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prints "Main$$Lambda$1/0x0000000801185840@38af3868"
        System.out.println((Supplier<String>) () -> {
            String s = "Akhilesh";
            return s;
        });

        Object obj = (Supplier<String>) () -> {
            String s = "Akhilesh";
            return s;
        };

        Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
            String s = "Akhilesh";
            return s;
        };

        // prints "Main$$Lambda$2/0x0000000801186040@72ea2f77"
        System.out.println(obj);
        // prints "Main$$Lambda$3/0x0000000801186440@33c7353a"
        System.out.println(supplier);
        // prints "Akhilesh"
        System.out.println(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

See [documentation for the java.util.function module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression is a short hand for an anonymous class implementation of a functional interface so you can only pass a lambda expression where the reference of a funtional interface.

There are overload of `println()` which take `int`, `float`, `ArrayList`, `HashMap` but there is no overload for `println()` which takes a functional interface as the input so you can't pass the lambda expression.

Comment: @NathanHughes thanks for information but what he is doing is an error, you can pass an anonymous inner class then i would definitely be a subclass of object and compiler knows that by  name name of interface, but when you pass a lambda , compiler does not know what interface you're talking about, so yes system does stop you from doing that in case of lambdas